# typo3 - direct mail - Unable to open file for reading

Tags: typo3, newsletter

When I am trying to send a new newsletter I get an error: Unable to open file for reading and then it points to a file which has the permission 777. I use the setup typo3 6.2.6 and directmail 4.0.1. I searched forge and found out, that allow_url_fopen must be on and it is on.

Comment: Which file is "a file"? At what point in the sending process does it happen exactly?

Comment: It´s a image file in my newslettertemplate. This error occurs when I am trying to send my newsletter. Invoke my mailer engine.